# Let $G$ be a group and $a\in G$. If $a$ has order $n$, why $a^2, a^3, .. a^{n-1}\in G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

When I was reading a proof, I saw this sentence:
Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group. Let $a\in G$ has order $n$. It is clear that $a^2, a^3, \dots, a^{n-1}\in G$.
I understand why $a^{n-1}\in G$, but I don't understand why $a^2, a^3, \dots, a^{n-2}\in G$. I think that the definition of a group doesn't guarantee this.
For example, I have a group $G=\{e,(0123),(0321)\}$, where $e$ is the identity. Clearly, $a=(0123)$ has order 4, and $a^3=(0321)\in G$, but $a^2=(02)(13)\notin G$.
Where am I wrong?
Appreciate anyone who is willing to offer help!

Comment: A group is supposed to be closed under its operation ...

Comment: Your example of $G$ isn't a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example isn't a group. A group needs to have the property that if $a \in G$ and $b \in G$ then $a \cdot b \in G$. This includes if $a$ and $b$ are equal, so in particular, if $a \in G$, then $a \cdot a= a^2 \in G$. Likewise $a^2 \cdot a= a^3 \in G$, and so on.

Comment: But the definition of a group given by my professor doesn't include this property...  He gives that a group should have associativity; there exists an identity; for every element in the group, there exists an inverse.

Comment: Probably the definition given by your professor was that a group has a binary operation $\cdot$ which takes two elements in your group and outputs another element in the group, right?

Comment: If not, please tell me what definition your professor uses.

Comment: I edit my previous comment, and added the definition given by my professor.

Comment: Surely your professor said that your group has an operation $\cdot$, right?

Comment: Yes. The operation is defined as: let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group, and $\cdot:G\times G\longrightarrow G$ is called the group operation.

Comment: The notation $\cdot : G \times G \to G$ quite literally means that as an operation, $\cdot$ takes two elements in $G$ and spits out another element in $G$.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean! Thanks! God wish I asked this! My professor didn't emphasize this, which confused me a lot.

Comment: Yeah it's a very important property of groups. Good luck going forward!